# Runtime error, invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: golang

Почему возникает ошибка: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` я работаю с прокси серверами и мне нужно получить headers с 2ip.ru где будет виден мой IP адрес. Прокси сервера у меня лежат в .txt файле там их около 10, всегда выбирается рандомный прокси-сервер, код:

```
func randInt(len int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(len)
} 

func PConn(host string, port int) {

    bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("proxy.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error ")
        fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "Details: "+ color.RedString("Error read file"))
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) /*Wait for close all threads.*/
        return /*exiting in program*/
    }

    str := string(bs) 
    randoms := strings.Split(str, "\r\n")
    bestProxyServer := randInt(len(randoms))
    fmt.Println(randoms[bestProxyServer])

    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://"+randoms[bestProxyServer])
    httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }
    req, err := httpClient.Get(host)

    if req != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "error "+ "HTTP-Error; "+ color.RedString("404[Bad]")+"\n")
    } else {
        defer req.Body.Close()
        fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "$http.proxy/response; "+ "Connection established; "+ color.GreenString("200[Ok]")+"\n")
        //fmt.Println("", "true. 200[ok]")
        fmt.Println("headers", req.Header)
    }

}
```

Закрывал при помощи `defer` где только возможно, все ровно вылетает одна и та же ошибка. Очень часто вылетают такие ошибки, что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например посмотрите кусок

```
if req != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "error "+ "HTTP-Error; "+ color.RedString("404[Bad]")+"\n")
} else {
    defer req.Body.Close()
    fmt.Fprintf(color.Output, "$http.proxy/response; "+ "Connection established; "+ color.GreenString("200[Ok]")+"\n")
    //fmt.Println("", "true. 200[ok]")
    fmt.Println("headers", req.Header)
}
```

Если req != nil - тогда печатать, иначе (если req == nil) - req.Body.Close() - вот тут гарантировано будет обращение к нулевому указателю, т.к. в эту ветку программа попадёт только если req == nil.

Вероятно это опечатка и в условии должно быть err != nil.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была в опечатке)